# C# how to add a column of hours which are in string format

Tags: c#, datetime

working hours of a person in my program will be shown like this:

[image]

As they are in string format how can I calculate the total hours of a person?

Comment: Do you *have* to have them in string format instead of as TimeSpan values which are simply *formatted* as strings?

Comment: till now yes but if there is no other option I can do this calculations before inserting them into my gridview so that I will have their TimeSpan.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give us more context. Where has the information come from? What's the source format?

Comment: Ok I made them to TimeStamp but when the sum of hours exceed one day it won't be like e.g. 26 hours it would be 1.2:0:0 how can I show it like 26 hours!

Comment: The sum will still be 26 hours... you just need to format it to use `TotalHours` instead of `Hours` if you want to display it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the values as `TimeSpans`, so you can perform calculations on them, and only convert to strings for display purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You indeed need to store the values as TimeSpan instances.

But maybe they are given to you as strings. In that case you can convert them to TimeSpan using TimeSpan.Parse(), see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parse.aspx